# RPI3 Ubuntu 16.04 ncsdk install error.No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.4.0

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, ncsdk

Tried the following on a raspberrypi3 to obtain a full NCSDK installation

1. Installed ubunuMate. Result Release: 16.04.4 LTS code: xenial installed without complaint
2. ran script to

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/movidius/ncsdk
   sudo make install
   ```

Errors reported as follows:

> ```
> No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.4.0
> You are using pip version 8.1.1 however version 9.0.1 is available
> ```

`pip -V` returns 9.0.1
`pip2 -V` returns 9.0.1
`pip 3 -V` returns 8.1.1

Presumably pip3 is executing. I tried several `apt get install` methods to update pip2 and pip3

Movidius environment spec mentions 64 bit machines. My Rasperrypi3 is 64 bit but does the Ubuntu installation run in 64 bitmode and does this matter?

Can I build the ncsdk on a 32bit intel pc or must it be a 64 bit pc running Ubuntu (which flavour?)

Answer (score 1):

The prerequisites to install and configure Intel® Movidius™ Neural Compute SDK on Raspberry Pi includes:

- x86-64 with Ubuntu (64 bit) 16.04 Desktop
- Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Stretch (starting with SDK 1.09.xx)

For further clarification refer the following link:

https://movidius.github.io/ncsdk/install.html

Please try using Raspbian OS instead of UbuntuMate as it is specified in prerequisites.